# Access HDFS data through Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, apache-zeppelin

I am trying access the HDFS data through Zeppelin by using Spark interpreter.

Here is my code:

```
val bankText = sc.parallelize(hdfs://hadoop:8020/user/zeppelin/bank.csv)

case class Bank(age: Integer, job: String, marital: String, education: String, balance: Integer)

val bank = bankText.map(s => s.split(";")).filter(s => s(0) != "\"age\"").map(
    s => Bank(s(0).toInt, 
            s(1).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(2).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(3).replaceAll("\"", ""),
            s(5).replaceAll("\"", "").toInt
        )
).toDF()
bank.registerTempTable("bank")
```

i am not getting any error in the output prompt but, i am getting error message in top right corner.

Here is that scrrenshot.
[image]

Comment: Try putting the action to show the dataframe on your dataframe "bank" and then see if there is any error coming in zeppelin logs

Comment: Why do you need to set `hdfs://hadoop:8020`? Is Spark not already configured to Hadoop? Can you run this code fine in Spark shell? Also, you should be using SparkCSV reader to read file with `;` delimiter. (using split isn't perfect)

Comment: @cricket_007 my main goal is access hdfs data from zeppelin, code is copied from zeppelin examples, i can change the code.

Comment: Please check the interpreter log

Comment: "Zeppelin" code isn't a thing. And Zeppelin is (very likely) not the problem, your Spark configuration is, which must be edited outside of Zeppelin... Therefore, please **try** using Spark shell, get it working, then continue on to setup Zeppelin

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is this statement:

```
val bankText = sc.parallelize(hdfs://hadoop:8020/user/zeppelin/bank.csv)
```

I assume what you meant to put is:

```
val bankText = sc.parallelize("hdfs://hadoop:8020/user/zeppelin/bank.csv")
```

but this, while it will compile, won't give you what you expect. `parallelize()` is used to turn a Scala `Seq` - in this case a `String` - into an RDD, each row of which is a member of the `Seq`. In other words, you will have an RDD where each row is a character from the string `"hdfs://hadoop:8020/user/zeppelin/bank.csv"`. The first row will be 'h', the second will be 'd', and so on.

Long story short, to read from a character-delimited file in HDFS, the command you want is

```
val bankText = spark.read.option("sep", ";").csv("hdfs://hadoop:8020/user/zeppelin/bank.csv")
```